# Custom Numbering list

Tags: html, list

How to set numbering list with a custom number like this:
1). Item
2). Item
     a). Sub Item
     b). Sub Item

Please help....

Comment: Format your answer properly. It's not readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a list into another list, just like this:

```
<ol id="main">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>        
    <ol>
        <li>Item 3.1</li>
        <li>Item 3.2</li>
    </ol>
</ol>
```

than you can change what is in front of each item by CSS. For example like this:

```
ol#main {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
ol#main > ol {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

more about `list-style-type` property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp
more about `list-style` property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style.asp